# Several setMessage updates (ProgressBar)

Tags: android, progress-bar

```
new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            Progress.setMessage("Scanning Apps ...");
            int CurrentNumber = 0;
            while (CurrentNumber <= 99) {
            Progress.setProgress(CurrentNumber);
            Progress.setMessage(CurrentNumber + "");
            sleep(100);
            CurrentNumber ++;
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}.start();
```

So.. this code is not working :(

What am I doing wrong?

Without `Progress.setMessage(CurrentNumber + "");` it is working perfectly...

Answer (score 2):

write handler 
e.g.

```
    private Handler handler = new Handler() {
         @Override
         public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
             //set message here
         }
        };
```

Comment: Could you add some more details/explanations?

Comment: feeela please see this link : http://crodrigues.com/updating-the-ui-from-a-background-thread-on-android/

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) which handles progress updates, giving you a chance to set your progress message on the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that Progress is an instance of ProgressDialog. You can only update the UI on the UI (main) thread. Read about threading and the UI on the dev [site](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html).

Comment: When I only change the Message one, it is working all right for me...

But when I do it in a loop the loop always stops in the middle of doing it...

Comment: You can only modify the UI on the UI thread meaning you should not do it the way you are doing it. Read the article at the link I posted.